# How do I split text by every other line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

Or in other words by every two lines? Right now i only seem to be able to split by every line.

the list would be something like this copied into the text area:

Style:

CGV7

Fabric:

95% Polyester, 5% Elastane

Source:

Imported

Guarantee:

Lifetime Warranty

this is the result I want

Style: CGV7

Fabric: 95% Polyester, 5% Elastane

Source: Imported

Guarantee: Lifetime Warranty

here is my code:

```
  <textarea id="tables" name="" cols="78" rows="10" onchange="splitIt()"> 
  </textarea>

  function splitIt(){
     var items = [];
     var tablevalues = document.getElementById("tables").value;
     var splitItems =tablevalues.split(/\n/);
       items.push(splitItems);
       console.log(items);
 }
```

Comment: How will the initial words be introduced into the code? Will these be text in the HTML? Will it be an array of strings? What HTML is the `tables` element?

Comment: I believe it will be text in the html, the words are typically copied into a textarea box

Comment: thats why im trying to put the text into an array split up by every other line.

Comment: Please edit your question to show all the related code (including HTML).

Comment: @ScottMarcus i just edited it and put the text that is being entered and the result I am looking for, hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let p = text.split('\n');
  let results = '';

  p.forEach((x, index) => {
    if (index%2 !== 0) {
      results = results + x + '\n';
    }
    else {
      results = results +x;
    }
  });
  console.log(results);
```

You can achieve this by splitting the whole string on `\n` and then you can add it back on every odd element concat.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
str.replace(/[\r\n]/g, " ")
   .split(" ")
   .filter((x) => x.trim())
   .join("\n")
```

Updated, this might be short and cool :)

```
a.split(/:\n/).join(":")
```